# How do I get into a Docker container's shell?

Tags: docker, docker-container

I'm getting started working with Docker. I'm using the `WordPress` base *image* and `docker-compose`.

I'm trying to **ssh** into one of the containers to inspect the files/directories that were created during the initial build. I tried to run `docker-compose run containername ls -la`, but that didn't do anything. Even if it did, I'd rather have a console where I can traverse the directory structure, rather than run a single command. What is the right way to do this with Docker?

Comment: So it sounds like the answer is docker attach. But how can I get to that from docker-compose?

Comment: Use `docker exec` http://askubuntu.com/a/543057/35816 . Get the container id using `docker ps`

Comment: `sudo docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash <container_name>` gets you into the container interactively. Then one can inspect the file system in the container using `cd <path>`

Comment: @Sergei That's incorrect, docker run takes an image name, not a container ID. I was confused about running containers for a long time which is why I ended up writing https://blog.andrewray.me/towards-a-strong-mental-model-of-docker/

Comment: 1. list your containers: `docker ps -a`; 2. `sudo docker start <container_name>` if you already have a container running. See [container start](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_start/) for more parameters. 3. Then use the exec command.

Comment: docker-compose is now integrated into docker, so the command recommanded is now `docker compose ...` without the dash.

Comment: @AndyRay https://blog.andrewray.me/towards-a-strong-mental-model-of-docker/ is a broken link, do you have a new link for it?

Answer (score 2960, accepted):

`docker attach` will let you connect to your Docker container, but this isn't really the same thing as `ssh`.  If your container is running a webserver, for example, `docker attach` will probably connect you to the *stdout* of the web server process.  It won't necessarily give you a shell.

The `docker exec` command is probably what you are looking for; this will let you run arbitrary commands inside an existing container.  For example:

```
docker exec -it <mycontainer> bash
```

Of course, whatever command you are running must exist in the container filesystem.

In the above command `<mycontainer>` is the name or ID of the target container.  It doesn't matter whether or not you're using `docker compose`; just run `docker ps` and use either the ID (a hexadecimal string displayed in the first column) or the name (displayed in the final column).  E.g., given:

```
$ docker ps
d2d4a89aaee9        larsks/mini-httpd   "mini_httpd -d /cont   7 days ago          Up 7 days                               web
```

I can run:

```
$ docker exec -it web ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
18: eth0: <BROADCAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.3/16 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:acff:fe11:3/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I could accomplish the same thing by running:

```
$ docker exec -it d2d4a89aaee9 ip addr
```

Similarly, I could start a shell in the container;

```
$ docker exec -it web sh
/ # echo This is inside the container.
This is inside the container.
/ # exit
$
```

Comment: Also, `docker exec` only works on running containers (otherwise use `docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash` or similar).

Comment: for your convenience, `-it` is a combination of `-i` and `-t` which is `--interactive` ("Keep STDIN open even if not attached") respectively `--tty` (" Allocate a pseudo-TTY").

Comment: On Alpine Linux based containers you might not have bash, so if so, use sh instead.

Comment: When I execute this, I am having permission issues creating/editing files inside the container - once a file is created, the local user cannot edit it until I do `sudo chmod -R 777 /directory`

Comment: @L0j1k it is `docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash <imageid> --any --more --args`, just to clarify for people

Comment: @AlexanderMills Yes, and to clarify further, those `--any --more --args` you have will be fed into whatever the image has defined as its `CMD` and not Docker (or if your image only defines an `ENTRYPOINT` and no `CMD`, then these options will be fed into `/bin/bash` as you've specified here). So for example any other `docker run` options (e.g. `--net "host"`) need to go before the `<imageid>`.

Comment: You migh twant to replace `bash` by `sh`

Comment: You'll note I show exactly that at the end of the answer :)

Comment: for entrypoint to work you mush include bash or sh in the container image

Comment: Definitely the answer. Also, to access as the root user, which is very common:
```docker exec -it -u root <mycontainer> bash```

Comment: Please note that there are containers that (for security reasons) do not have bash or some form of shell bundled in its files.

Comment: That's true! In this case -- depending on what you're trying to do -- `nsenter` can be useful, but sometimes your only option is `docker inspect` to find the root filesystem directory and just explore it directly.

Comment: Also consider adding the --rm param to clean up the container automatically after you are done: `docker exec --rm -it <mycontainer> bash`

Comment: `docker exec -it web ip addr`

Error response from daemon: No such container: web

Comment: That error message looks pretty clear: you've either mistyped the named of the container or it has exited and is no longer running.

Comment: OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Answer (score 507):

To bash into a running container, type this:

```
docker exec -t -i container_name /bin/bash
```

or

```
docker exec -ti container_name /bin/bash
```

or

```
docker exec -ti container_name sh
```

Comment: Presuming it is a Linux container?

Comment: /bin/bash wasnt required just bash did it for me

Comment: I would prefer `docker exec -it` instead of `docker exec -t -i`

Comment: @nakamin According to the docs, adding the -u or --user flag will allow you to specify the user. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Comment: just bash will work out instead on /bin/bash

Comment: To get the container name, run `docker ps` and use the container id. E.g. `docker exec -t -i 5ae8669be8f8 /bin/bash`

Comment: how about an exited container? The problem is the container stops so fast so I don't have the chance to do exec it. And for the sake of learning I want to do on the container directly, not create a new one from the image

Comment: You cannot enter a non-running container. Practice with a container that keeps running like a MySQL container or any other kind of server.

Comment: docker exec -ti container_name sh. it's work for me

Answer (score 128):

*Historical note: At the time I wrote this answer, the title of the question was: **"How to ssh into a docker container?"***

As other answers have demonstrated, it is common to execute and interact with preinstalled commands (including shells) in a locally-accessible running container using [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/), *rather than SSH*:

```
docker exec -it (container) (command)
```

---

*Note: The below answer is based on Ubuntu (of 2016).  Some translation of the installation process will be required for non-Debian containers.*

Let's say, for reasons that are your own, you really do want to use SSH. It takes a few steps, but it can be done. Here are the commands that you would run inside the container to set it up...

```
apt-get update
apt-get install openssh-server

mkdir /var/run/sshd
chmod 0755 /var/run/sshd
/usr/sbin/sshd

useradd --create-home --shell /bin/bash --groups sudo username ## includes 'sudo'
passwd username ## Enter a password

apt-get install x11-apps ## X11 demo applications (optional)
ifconfig | awk '/inet addr/{print substr($2,6)}' ## Display IP address (optional)
```

Now you can even run graphical applications (if they are installed in the container) using X11 forwarding to the SSH client:

```
ssh -X username@IPADDRESS
xeyes ## run an X11 demo app in the client
```

Here are some related resources:

- [openssh-server doesn't start in Docker container](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/178337/6764)
- [How to get bash or ssh into a running container in background mode?](https://askubuntu.com/q/505506/11522)
- [Can you run GUI applications in a Linux Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16296753)
- Other useful approaches for graphical access found with search: Docker X11
- [If you run SSHD in your Docker containers, you're doing it wrong!](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil)

Comment: At the time I wrote this answer, the title of the question was: "How to ssh into a docker container?"  Over the years, the question and answers have been edited by interlopers and bots -- in some cases, possibly changing the intent.  My previous comment to this effect was anonymously deleted.

Comment: [How many edits automatically turn my answer into a Community Wiki answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293826/86967)

Answer (score 66):

If the container has already exited (maybe due to some error), you can do:

```
$ docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/bash image_name
```

or

```
$ docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/sh image_name
```

or

```
$ docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/bash image_name
```

to create a new container and get a shell into it.

Here is the breakdown of the command:

```
--rm: This option specifies that the container should be automatically removed when it is finished.

-it: These options allow the container to be run interactively with a pseudo-tty terminal. The -i option stands for interactive mode and the -t option stands for a pseudo-tty terminal.

--entrypoint /bin/bash: This option specifies the entry point for the container as /bin/bash, which is the shell program.

image_name: This is the name of the Docker image on which the container will be based.
```

Since you specified --rm, the container would be deleted when you exit the shell.

Answer (score 55):

If you're here looking for a Docker Compose-specific answer like I was, it provides an easy way in without having to look up the generated container ID.

`docker-compose exec` takes the name of the service as per your `docker-compose.yml` file.

So to get a Bash shell for your 'web' service, you can do:

```
$ docker-compose exec web bash
```

Comment: `docker-compose run` works as well, if your container doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 31):

Start a session into a Docker container using this command:

```
sudo docker exec -i -t (container ID) bash
```

Comment: or a little shorter: `sudo docker exec -it <container ID> bash`

Comment: or even shorter `docker exec -it <container-id> sh` :)

Answer (score 30):

**Notice**: this answer promotes a tool I've written.

I've created a containerized SSH server that you can 'stick' to any running container. This way you can create compositions with every container. The only requirement is that the container has Bash.

The following example would start an SSH server attached to a container with name 'my-container'.

```
docker run -d -p 2222:22 \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  -e CONTAINER=my-container -e AUTH_MECHANISM=noAuth \
  jeroenpeeters/docker-ssh

ssh localhost -p 2222
```

When you connect to this SSH service (with your SSH client of choice) a Bash session will be started in the container with name 'my-container'.

For more pointers and documentation see: https://github.com/jeroenpeeters/docker-ssh

Comment: That's pretty sweet. The big advantage of doing it this way is you're getting a fully functional terminal. When I used the "docker exec" approach then I couldn't clear the terminal content, `less` was showing a warning each time I run it etc. Using Jeroen's container is giving me a much better experience so far. Just make sure to **check out the documentation**. The sample command in the response doesn't seem valid any more.

Comment: it is a great tool. Do you know how can i use it as a jenkins pipeline docker agent? i Want jenkins to transfer some files by SCP to a remote host and execute them with SSH

Comment: Docker On Windows : docker run -d -p 2222:22 -v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -e CONTAINER=my-container -e AUTH_MECHANISM=noAuth --name node-manager jeroenpeeters/docker-ssh

Answer (score 27):

If you're using Docker on Windows and want to get shell access to a container, use this:

```
winpty docker exec -it <container_id> sh
```

Most likely, you already have [Git Bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) installed. **If you don't, make sure to install it.**

Comment: Presumes a Linux Docker container?

Answer (score 27):

In some cases your image can be Alpine-based. In this case it will throw:

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting
>   container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in
>   $PATH": unknown

Because `/bin/bash` doesn't exist. Instead of this you should use:

```
docker exec -it 9f7d99aa6625 ash
```

or

```
docker exec -it 9f7d99aa6625 sh
```

Answer (score 21):

To connect to cmd in a Windows container, use

```
docker exec -it d8c25fde2769 cmd
```

Where ***d8c25fde2769*** is the container id.

Answer (score 15):

To inspect files, run `docker run -it <image> /bin/sh` to get an interactive terminal. The list of images can be obtained by `docker images`. In contrary to `docker exec` this solution works also in case when an image doesn't start (or quits immediately after running).

Comment: Presuming a Linux Docker image?

Answer (score 15):

## GOINSIDE SOLUTION

install `goinside` command line tool with:

```
sudo npm install -g goinside
```

and go inside a docker container with a proper terminal size with:

```
goinside docker_container_name
```

---

### old answer

We've put this snippet in `~/.profile`:

```
goinside(){
    docker exec -it $1 bash -c "stty cols $COLUMNS rows $LINES && bash";
}
export -f goinside
```

Not only does this make everyone able to get inside a running container with:

```
goinside containername
```

It also solves a long lived [problem about fixed Docker container terminal sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786615/docker-number-of-lines-in-terminal-changing-inside-docker). Which is very annoying if you face it.

Also if you follow [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49281526/5284370) you'll have command completion for your docker container names too.

Comment: Thanks. It works like a charm, at least for those images which have bash already included. Might not work for alpine based images, however, can be fixed with a different function specifically written for sh/ash etc.

Answer (score 14):

**It is simple**!

List out all your Docker images:

```
sudo docker images
```

On my system it showed the following output:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
bash                latest              922b9cc3ea5e        9 hours ago
14.03 MB
ubuntu              latest              7feff7652c69        5 weeks ago         81.15 MB
```

I have two Docker images on my PC. Let's say I want to run the first one.

```
sudo docker run -i -t ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
```

This will give you terminal control of the container. Now you can do all type of shell operations inside the container. Like doing `ls` will output all folders in the root of the file system.

```
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

Answer (score 14):

## 2022 Solution

Consider another option

### Why do you need it?

There is a bunch of modern docker-images that are based on [distroless](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless) base images (**they don't have `/bin/bash` either `/bin/sh`**) so it becomes impossible to `docker exec -it {container-name} bash` into them.

### How to shell-in any container

Use [opener](https://github.com/artemkaxboy/docker-opener):

- requires to [add alias](https://github.com/artemkaxboy/docker-opener#installation) in your environment `opener wordpress`
- works anywhere `docker run --rm -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock artemkaxboy/opener wordpress`

Instead of `wordpress` you can use name or id or image-name of any container you want to connect

---

### How it works

[Opener](https://github.com/artemkaxboy/docker-opener) is a set of python scripts wrapped-up to a docker image. It finds target container by any unique attribute (name, id, port, image), tries to connect to target using `bash`. If `bash` is not found opener tries to connect using `sh`. Finally if `sh` is not found either opener installs `busybox` into target container and connects to the target using busybox shell, opener deletes `busybox` during disconnection.

Comment: That is very cool, I tried this and it works great. I love how simple the scripts are that it runs. I never would have thought to try installing busybox in order to get a shell environment working in a docker container.

Comment: Love how simple this is. Shell alias set, so this it the last time I'll have to go looking for help on this. Thank you for the tool!

Answer (score 12):

I've created a terminal function for easier access to the container's terminal. Maybe it's useful to you guys as well:

So the result is, instead of typing:

```
docker exec -it [container_id] /bin/bash
```

you'll write:

```
dbash [container_id]
```

Put the following in your ~/.bash_profile (or whatever else that works for you), then open a new terminal window and enjoy the shortcut:

```
#usage: dbash [container_id]
dbash() {
    docker exec -it "$1" /bin/bash
}
```

Answer (score 10):

```
$ docker exec -it <Container-Id> /bin/bash
```

Or depending on the shell, it can be

```
$ docker exec -it <Container-Id> /bin/sh
```

You can get the **container-Id** via `docker ps` command

`-i` = interactive

`-t` = to allocate a psuedo-TTY

Answer (score 9):

### 2024 version

Use `exec` with `sh` as a short-form:

```bash
docker exec -it <CONTAINER_ID or CONTAINER_NAME> sh
```

You can find `CONTAINER_ID` (1st column) or `CONTAINER_NAME` (last column) by performing `docker ps` & get output that looks like:

```bash
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS                 PORTS                                       NAMES
8e5611ba2567   nextjs:0.0.1   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 hours ago   Up 3 hours             0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, :::3000->3000/tcp   web
f3967286c492   redis:7.2.4    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 hours ago   Up 3 hours (healthy)   0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp, :::6379->6379/tcp   web_redis
```

For `nextjs:0.0.1`, `CONTAINER_ID` is `8e5611ba2567` & `CONTAINER_NAME` is `web`. To get into `web` container, type:

```bash
docker exec -it 8e5611ba2567 sh
# or docker exec -it web sh (both are same)
```

For `redis:7.2.4`, `CONTAINER_ID` is `f3967286c492` & `CONTAINER_NAME` is `web_redis`. To get into `web_redis` container, type:

```bash
docker exec -it f3967286c492 sh
# or docker exec -it web_redis sh (both are same)
```

Answer (score 8):

you can interact with the terminal in docker container by passing the option -ti

```
docker run --rm -ti <image-name>
eg: docker run --rm -ti ubuntu
```

-t stands for terminal
-i stands for interactive

Answer (score 8):

To exec into a running container named `test`, below is the following commands

If the container has `bash` shell

```
docker exec -it test /bin/bash
```

If the container has `bourne` shell and most of the cases it's present

```
docker run -it test /bin/sh
```

Answer (score 8):

There are at least 2 options depending on the target.

**Option 1:** Create a new bash process and join into it *(easier)*

- Sample start: `docker exec -it <containername> /bin/bash`
- Quit: type `exit`
- Pro: Does work on all containers (not depending on CMD/Entrypoint)
- Contra: Creates a new process with own session and own environment-vars

**Option 2:** Attach to the already running bash *(better)*

- Sample start: `docker attach --detach-keys ctrl-d <containername>`
- Quit: use keys `ctrl` and `d`
- Pro: Joins the exact same running bash which is in the container. You have same the session and same environment-vars.
- Contra: Only works if CMD/Entrypoint is an interactive bash like `CMD ["/bin/bash"]` or `CMD ["/bin/bash", "--init-file", "myfile.sh"]` **AND** if container has been started with interactive options like `docker run -itd <image>` (-i=interactive, -t=tty and -d=deamon [opt])

We found option 2 more useful. For example we changed `apache2-foreground` to a normal background `apache2` and started a `bash` after that.

Answer (score 7):

`docker exec` will definitely be a solution. An easy way to work with the question you asked is by **mounting the directory inside Docker to the local system's directory**.

So that you can view the changes in local path instantly.

```
docker run -v /Users/<path>:/<container path>
```

Comment: your command is actually mounting the host's directory into the container.

Comment: Yeah!
Take a backup to another directory and then mount the volume, then move the backup to the mounted folder.

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
docker attach <container name/id here>
```

The other way, albeit there is a danger to it, is to use `attach`, but if you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to exit the session, you will also stop the container. If you just want to see what is happening, use `docker logs -f`.

```
:~$ docker attach --help
Usage:  docker attach [OPTIONS] CONTAINER

Attach to a running container

Options:
      --detach-keys string   Override the key sequence for detaching a container
      --help                 Print usage
      --no-stdin             Do not attach STDIN
      --sig-proxy            Proxy all received signals to the process (default true)
```

Answer (score 7):

Use this command:

```
docker exec -it containerid /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 5):

This is best if you don't want to specify an entry point in your docker build file..

```
sudo docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash <container_name>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have Docker installed with `Kitematic`, you can use the GUI. Open `Kitematic` from the Docker icon and in the `Kitematic` window select your container, and then click on the `exec` icon.

You can see the container log and lots of container information (in settings tab) in this GUI too.

[image: Select Kitematic from menu]

[image: Click on exec]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Docker Compose then this will take you inside a Docker container.

```
docker-compose run container_name /bin/bash
```

Inside the container it will take you to WORKDIR defined in the Dockerfile. You can change your work directory by

```
WORKDIR directory_path # E.g  /usr/src -> container's path
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, for some reason(s) I need to check all the network involved information in each container. So the following commands must be valid in a container...

```
ip
route
netstat
ps
...
```

I checked through all these answers, none were helpful for me. I’ve searched information in other websites. I won’t add a super link here, since it’s not written in English. So I just put up this post with a summary solution for people who have the same requirements as me.

Say you have one running container named light-test. Follow the steps below.

- `docker inspect light-test -f {{.NetworkSettings.SandboxKey}}`. This command will get reply like `/var/run/docker/netns/xxxx`.
- Then `ln -s /var/run/docker/netns/xxxx  /var/run/netns/xxxx`. The directory may not exist, do `mkdir /var/run/netns` first.
- Now you may execute `ip netns exec xxxx ip addr show` to explore network world in container.

PS. `xxxx` is always the same value received from the first command. And of course, any other commands are valid, i.e. `ip netns exec xxxx netstat -antp|grep 8080`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options we can connect to the docker terminal directly with these method `shell` and `bash` but usually bash is not supported and defualt sh is supported terminal
To sh into the running container, type this:

> docker exec -it container_name/container_ID sh

To bash into a running container, type this:

> docker exec -it container_name/container_ID bash

and you want to use only bash terminal than you can install the bash terminal in your `Dockerfile` like `RUN apt install bash -y`

Answer (score 1):

There is one more method I currently utilize, but I've been exploring a more user-friendly alternative.

With the Windows [Docker Desktop GUI](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop/), there's a feature that not only lets you open a direct shell on a container but also opens that shell in an external terminal. Essentially, it creates an instance of your selected terminal, and every command thereafter automatically utilizes 'docker exec -it ' without the need for manual input each time.
[image: Docker Desktop]

Answer (score 1):

There now is an official docker command for this:

```
docker debug <container or image>
```

It allows you to get a shell (bash/fish/zsh) into any container. It also works for stopped containers and images. Essentially it's a replacement of `docker exec -it <container> sh` but with more features and less constraints (eg the debug shell has an `install` command to add further tools).
Using `docker debug` does not modify your container/image (unless you explicitly do so, and only possible for running containers)

See [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/debug/) for more details and examples.

Disclaimer: As of now, this is a paid feature and requires Docker Desktop >= 4.27. Ie., if you want to do this with docker-ce, `docker exec -it <container> sh` still is the valid answer.

Comment: docker: 'debug' is not a docker command.

Comment: Are you using docker desktop version 4.27 or higher? As mentioned in the disclaimer and in the referenced docs page, docker debug is a new command available as of docker desktop 4.27.

Comment: Understood, thank you! I am using Rancher Desktop 1.12.3 with docker as a backend Client - Version: 24.0.7-rd (output of docker version command )

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [nsenter](https://blog.docker.com/tag/nsenter/).

```
PID=$(docker inspect --format {{.State.Pid}} <container_name_or_ID>)
nsenter --target $PID --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid
```

Comment: There are a number of problems with `nsenter`.  The first is that it requires you to have physical access to the docker host, which is not a given (you may be working with a remote docker API).  Also, running under `nsenter` exempts you from several of the security and resource restrictions that Docker puts in place (which can be a pro or a con, depending on your environment).

Comment: Even the author of nsenter [says](https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter/issues/19#issuecomment-61248200) to use `docker exec` these days.

Comment: @larsks Yes, both have their own benefits. For example, [this one](https://github.com/dockerfile/mariadb/issues/3) is a benefit of nsenter over `docker exec`. `docker exec` looks more elegant to me.

Comment: @L0j1k Just to be less confusing: the post you referred is not by the author of nsenter, but the author of a Docker image which runs nsenter.

Answer (score -4):

For docker-compose up (Docker4Drupal)

```
docker-compose exec php bash
```

I use [Docker for Drupal](https://github.com/wodby/docker4drupal) on a Linux laptop. After running the container I use '`docker-compose exec php bash`' to connect with the container so I can run drush commandos. It works fine for me.