# Docker number of lines in terminal changing inside docker

Tags: bash, docker, terminal, tput

I would like to know how to change the following behavior. Let's say my terminal has **28** lines. Then I use the following commands:

```
$ tput lines # my terminal
28
$ docker run  --rm  -it ubuntu:16.04 tput lines  # docker container
24  ## WHY??
$ docker run  --rm  -it ubuntu:16.04 bash # docker container inside command
root@810effa2777c:/# tput lines
28
```

As you can see, even when all the results should be **28**, when I'm calling the container as `docker run  --rm  -it ubuntu:16.04 tput lines` it always gives me 24 despite the size of my terminal. This is not only with the ubuntu container, I also tried with debian (`docker run --rm -it debian tput lines`) and I'm having the same result 24.

The purpose of this is to use the [mdp presentation tool](https://github.com/visit1985/mdp) which takes into account the lines in your terminal. When my implementation failed, I tried some other person's [docker implementation](https://hub.docker.com/r/jess/mdp/) but I ran to the same error.

Here's my error in an image:

[image: Docker number of lines in terminal changing inside docker]

Does anyone has any idea what it could be and how can this be solved?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Update Sept. 2018: check if docker 18.06 has the same issue ([it should not](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25450#issuecomment-363886751), after [`moby/moby` issue 33794](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33794#issuecomment-406814439), and also [`moby/moby` issue 35407](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35407) and [PR 37172](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/37172), part of the [18.06 release notes](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/releases/tag/v18.06.0-ce)).

---

2016:

The [Ubuntu Dockerfile](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/e68c4b0d4c860a8e0547cfea6f1b07f0adb9ff46/yakkety/Dockerfile#L43) includes:

```
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

That means the default `ENTRYPOINT` is `sh -c` (and I doubt `tput line` works well in a `sh` session, since [tput](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/tput.htm) uses `terminfo` database, which might be set only for bash in that image)

You could try overwrite `ENTRYPOINT` with `bash -c` and check if that works better.

That does not work from command line though:

```
docker run --entrypoint /bin/bash --rm  -it ubuntu:16.04 -i -c 'tput lines'
24
```

I will check the option of defining a custom image.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
```

The result is the same though:

```
docker run --rm  -it u 'tput lines'
24
```

This however "works":

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash" ]
```

With:

```
docker@default:/c/Users/vonc/prog/testsu$ docker run --rm  -it u -i -c 'ls; tput lines'
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
48
```

There might be a synchronization issue, as the same command does return 24 from time to time.

Actually, the following *always* return "not 24" with:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-l", "-i", "-c" ]

docker run --rm  -it u -c 'sleep 0.1; ls; tput lines'
48
```

The [OP silgon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2237916/silgon) proposes [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786615/docker-number-of-lines-in-terminal-changing-inside-docker/38825323?noredirect=1#comment65021981_38825323):

```
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/bash ubuntu:16.04 -c "sleep 0.1 && tput lines"
```

---

As [BMitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596285/bmitch) comments [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786615/docker-number-of-lines-in-terminal-changing-inside-docker/38825323?noredirect=1#comment65021464_38825323):

> Given the success of sleep my suspicion is that docker spins up the container with the running command, and once up, the client attaches to the running container. 
>   Typically something that takes milliseconds.

That gave me another idea:

```
docker@default:/c/Users/vonc/prog/testsu$ 
docker run --entrypoint='/bin/bash' --name ub -d -it ubuntu:16.04
  0d9b8783afbb5e3ff4232da071d3f357985351ea1ce4d142bf6617ac456fb76b
docker@default:/c/Users/vonc/prog/testsu$ 
d attach ub
  root@0d9b8783afbb:/# tput lines
  48
  root@0d9b8783afbb:/# exit
exit
docker@default:/c/Users/vonc/prog/testsu$ drmae
0d9b8783afbb5e3ff4232da071d3f357985351ea1ce4d142bf6617ac456fb76b
```

A `tput lines` within an attached session works just fine.
(On the `drmae` alias, see "[How to remove old and unused Docker images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32723127/6309)")

---

[thajeztah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811501/thajeztah) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786615/docker-number-of-lines-in-terminal-changing-inside-docker/38825323#comment65022882_38825323):

> the container is created, then started with the defaults (`80x24`), and after that (when `-it`), a session is attached.
>   The session is specifying the size of the terminal;

See "[Resize a container TTY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.24/#/resize-a-container-tty)" API.

```
 DEBU[0244] Calling POST /v1.25/containers/c42fd5c4eb79c06fd7f9912b8359022f7d93887afbb33b57a67ed8bb7bfee4‌​3a/resize?h=46&w=221
```

For more, see [docker issue 25450](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/25450#issuecomment-238216897).
It is related to [issue 10341 "Container create or start should accept height/width params"](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10341). [Aleksa Sarai (cyphar)](https://github.com/cyphar) adds (**Sept. 2016**):

> This has actually popped up again inside the runtime-spec ([opencontainers/runtime-spec PR 563](https://github.com/opencontainers/runtime-spec/pull/563)).
>   **Basically, since Windows requires the ability to set the console size on first start, we might end up adding it for all platforms**.

---

The [OP silgon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2237916/silgon) points out to the code in [`api/client/container/run.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/506234e3f0f6d8f8a0629e09f38dfe96ada025c2/api/client/container/run.go):

```
// Telling the Windows daemon the initial size of the tty during start makes
// a far better user experience rather than relying on subsequent resizes
// to cause things to catch up.
if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
    hostConfig.ConsoleSize[0], hostConfig.ConsoleSize[1] = dockerCli.GetTtySize()
}
```

With the logical question:

> would it make sense to use this property on Linux as well, and set the initial console size using that value?

[Kenfe-Mickaël Laventure (`mlaventure`)](https://github.com/mlaventure) is on it, and a new patch could make it to [Docker 1.13](https://github.com/docker/docker/milestone/56).

Comment: Your command is not working (at least not for me), it throws me the following error `docker: Error response from daemon: /bin/bash -c: no such file or directory` which is weird. However, based on your command I figured I could use `docker run --rm  -it ubuntu:16.04 bash -c "tput lines"`, thus I change `sh -c` to `/bin/bash -c++ as you said. This command runs, but it also gives 24 as the output as I specified in my question.

Comment: @silgon I leave that answer for now, as I think the main difference between your commands is the bash session. However, even with a custom image, tput still returns 24

Comment: @silgon There seems to be a synchronization issue: Try *severl times* the last command I mention in my (edited) answer: most of the time, it does not return 24.

Comment: @silgon Actually, with a sleep in front of the tput command, the result is *never* 24.

Comment: Given the success of `sleep` my suspicion is that docker spins up the container with the running command, and once up, the client attaches to the running container. Typically something that takes milliseconds.

Comment: Just try it. Working perfectly well, thanks! Now I know how to troubleshoot it for other applications. Can you maybe change your command to `docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/bash ubuntu:16.04 -c "sleep 0.1 && tput lines"`. Thus it's a generic answer and it doesn't depend on the container you created. I'm accepting your answer already. =)
BTW. @VonC  according to the system I still need to wait 18h to award you the bounty. I tried and it didn't let me. Thanks again! ;)

Comment: @BMitch Thank you for the comment: I have included it as an annex in my answer for more visibility. I am not clear on why the command would be executed before the container is fully attached though.

Comment: Ok, thanks @VonC, I'll award the bounty tomorrow when the system allows me to do it. Quite an interesting problem in the end as BMitch commented, about how the command is run before the container being fully attached.

Comment: @VonC at the api level, what's likely happening is a "create", then a "start" (those two together make up "run), then an "attach". You can't attach to a container that isn't running yet and it's extra effort to make that a single atomic operation.

Comment: @BMitch does that mean the command is executed after create, but before start?

Comment: @vonc, my suspicion is that the command runs when you execute "start" but doesn't get the tty from the client until the "attach" completes.

Comment: I think @vonc's conclusion is correct; the container is *created*, then *started* with the defaults (80x24), and after that (when `-it`), a session is attached. The *session* is specifying the size of the terminal; `DEBU[0244] Calling POST /v1.25/containers/c42fd5c4eb79c06fd7f9912b8359022f7d93887afbb33b57a67ed8bb7bfee43a/resize?h=46&w=221`

Comment: @thaJeztah Good point, referring to the Resize TTY API (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.24/#/resize-a-container-tty). I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 45):

## UPDATE

you can now install `goinside` command line tool with:

```
sudo npm install -g goinside
```

and go inside a docker container with a proper terminal size with:

```
goinside docker_container_name
```

---

### Logic behind goinside

thanks to [@VonC answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38825323/5284370) we've got a solution for this problem with a simple bash snippet that we put in `~/.profile`:

```
goinside(){
    docker exec -it $1 bash -c "stty cols $COLUMNS rows $LINES && bash";
}
export -f goinside
```

now you are able to get inside a docker container without terminal size issues with:

`$ goinside containername`

---

**remember** to `source ~/.profile` before using the `goinside` function.

---

### enabling autocompletion in bash

(as it's shared in one of comments below) if you want to enable autocompletion for `goinside` you can use this snippet in `.profile`:

```
goinside(){
    docker exec -it $1 bash -c "stty cols $COLUMNS rows $LINES && bash";
}
_goinside(){
    COMPREPLY=( $(docker ps --format "{{.Names}}" -f name=$2) );
}
complete -F _goinside goinside;
export -f goinside;
```

---

### enabling autocompletion in zsh

if you are using `zsh` as your default terminal you can use this snippet inside your `~/.zshrc` file:

```
autoload bashcompinit
bashcompinit
goinside(){
    docker exec -it $1 bash -c "stty cols $COLUMNS rows $LINES && bash";
}
_goinside(){
    COMPREPLY=( $(docker ps --format "{{.Names}}" -f name=$2) );
}
complete -F _goinside goinside;
export goinside;
```

Comment: Also you can make completion. `_goinside(){
    COMPREPLY=( $(docker ps --format "{{.Names}}" -f name=$2) )
}` and then export it `complete -F _goinside goinsid`

Answer (score 5):

A nice way to run bash inside the container without encountering line problems is [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33794#issuecomment-380969582):

```
docker exec -e COLUMNS="`tput cols`" -e LINES="`tput lines`" -ti container bash
```

Answer (score 1):

The comments about `sh` versus terminfo are largely irrelevant.  The relevant part (not clear in the given answer) is the way the command is executed.  `tput` checks three features in the following order (using [`setupterm`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_terminfo.3x.html#h3-Initialization)):

1. the size of the terminal from the terminfo database (many descriptions do not give this information, but with `TERM=xterm`, it is **24** by **80**),
2. the actual number of lines if it can get that information from the operating system (i.e., *the current window size*), and
3. the `LINES` and `COLUMNS` environment variables.

A command which is run without an interactive shell *could* be executed in a way that precludes getting the *current window size*.  For example, that is a feature of `ssh` (the `-t` option).  Also, it would be possible (though pointless) for Docker to set the `LINES` and `COLUMNS` variables.

Either case (1) or (3) is enough to explain the behavior; introducing time-delays and races does not do that.

Comment: I have udated my answer: https://github.com/opencontainers/runtime-spec/pull/563 will take care of that for all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

It has been fixed in docker 18.06: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33794#issuecomment-406814439

Answer (score 1):

I just tested with version `Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a`. It seems to have the same problem. However, one of the guys in the [github issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25450) gave a [practical workaround](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25450#issuecomment-354284254):

```
docker run --rm -it -e COLUMNS=$COLUMNS -e LINES=$LINES -e TERM=$TERM -it ubuntu:16.04 tput lines
```