# Docker terminal size

Tags: docker

I'm running `docker 17.12.0-ce` under `ubuntu 16.04 Server`

After doing `docker exec -it ... bash` the terminal (putty) size change.

Before `stty size` gives `60 180` after `0 0`

So after entering the 80st character the next ones are placed at the begining of the line (not on the next line).

[image]

There is a solution ?  Something to configure in docker daemon ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker number of lines in terminal changing inside docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786615/docker-number-of-lines-in-terminal-changing-inside-docker)

Comment: On an another note, you said you are running docker under ubuntu server, but you say you are running putty, so I'm not sure what your host for docker really is. If it is windows, there is further information [on this github bug report](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25450).

Comment: I'm running putty on windows.  But docker is well on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35407) in Docker. [The fix](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/37172) was merged on 8th June 2018, so should be in some future Docker release.