# connect SQL to apache nifi

Tags: sql-server, apache-nifi

I'm new to nifi and i want to connect SQL server database  to nifi and create a data flow with the processors. how can I do this, can any one Help me with this clearly.

Thanks in Advance
sam

Answer (score 14):

Here are two great articles on getting information in and out of databases with NiFi:

1. http://www.batchiq.com/database-injest-with-nifi.html
2. http://www.batchiq.com/database-extract-with-nifi.html

They describe/illustrate how to configure a [DBCPConnectionPool](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool/index.html) service to provide connection(s) to an RDBMS, and example flows to extract data and ingest data.

Comment: i need to install SQL server-2012 in my machine which one i need to install. can share me the correct link of SQL server to connect it with nifi.

Comment: That link to DBCPConnectionPool is out of date. Currently it looks like v1.7.0 is here: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-dbcp-service-nar/1.7.0/org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool/ Sadly the docs use iframe so getting the direct link to the page loses the menu. Better to go to https://nifi.apache.org/docs.html and find the DBCPConnectionPool in the menu. Silly name for a component when you're searching for "database" or "JDBC" or "RDBMS" or something.

Answer (score 11):

Expanding on [mattyb answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41490177/458321)

If you are using the latest Hortonworks sandbox, or other setup that uses docker containers, read below.

You have to install the JDBC jar file *inside the docker*. For SQL Server, it should be 6.2 or above.

```
docker ps
docker exec -it <mycontainer uuid> bash
```

> [How do I get into a Docker container's shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172605/how-to-get-into-a-docker-container)
> will help you log into the container.

```
cd file:///usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/
mkdir jdbc
cd ./jdbc
wget https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/F/7/3F74A9B9-C5F0-43EA-A721-07DA590FD186/sqljdbc_6.2.2.0_enu.tar.gz
tar xvzf sqljdbc_6.2.2.0_enu.tar.gz
cp ./sqljdbc_6.2/enu/mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar ./
```

[image: Apache Nifi JDBC Database DBCPConnectionPool Setup]

```
jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.201:1433;databaseName=[your database]
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

You might need to replace the ip address with IPv4 address of your host found under `ipconfig` in Windows or `ifconfig` in Mac/Linux.

You may change `file:///usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/`  to any path you desire.

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you so much! I was about to bang my head against multiple walls, because I'm running in docker and did not know how this would be done from the container. I think it might be worth adding some code to this to allow the jdbc driver to be downloaded as part of the docker image so that you have the jdbc without having to exec into it

Comment: If you comment or link to a working example, I will be glad to add it

Comment: I'm actually in the process of working on a dockerfile so that we can use it for our solution. I will post it here once it's working :)

Comment: Just an FYI - the sqljdbc version 8.4.1 was throwing me an 'out of date' error and only got success when using the 6.2 version mentioned here.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on [TamusJRoyce's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47170497/2523968)

If you are running nifi via a docker image like `apache/nifi` or the aforementioned Hortonworks sandbox, the following should help you get the required driver on the image so that you don't need to `exec` into the container to do it manually.

See the comments below the docker file

```
FROM apache/nifi

USER root
RUN mkdir /lib/jdbc
WORKDIR /lib/jdbc
RUN wget https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/F/7/3F74A9B9-C5F0-43EA-A721-07DA590FD186/sqljdbc_6.2.2.0_enu.tar.gz
RUN tar xvzf sqljdbc_6.2.2.0_enu.tar.gz
RUN cp ./sqljdbc_6.2/enu/mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar ./

USER nifi

EXPOSE 8080 8443 10000 8000

WORKDIR ${NIFI_HOME}
ENTRYPOINT ["../scripts/start.sh"]
```

1. The above image uses `apache/nifi` as the base image. You can use any nifi docker image has a base if you would like.
2. You can specify any location for `lib/jdbc`, just remember that you need to use this as the reference for the file location so that it is referenced as `file:///lib/jdbc/mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar`
3. Lastly, switch back to the nifi user and finish off with the standard nifi image details. This will allow the image to run correctly.

Comment: Thanks for providing this answer. I am using NiFi 1.13 in Docker. I have followed your example, but my DBCPConnectionPool is stuck on `Enabling`. With the Error message `Can't load Database Driver`. Any other ideas I can try?

Comment: Without seeing the docker file, my only guess is that perhaps you have an incompatible driver specified in the `wget`, or perhaps the location of the `jar` that you need to specify in NiFi itself is not being found