# Unable to connect to MSSQL to Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying connecting Mssql server with Nifi but getting below error.
Configuration:
Host: 210c:a022:205:541d::1:87 , it is not considering entire IP.

[image]

[image]

Comment: try specifiying properties like this `jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.201:1433;databaseName=[your database]`
`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`

Comment: refer this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41489816/connect-sql-to-apache-nifi

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried IPv6 addresses with MSSQL & NiFi, but according to MS docs, your connection string should look like:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://;serverName=3ffe:8311:eeee:f70f:0:5eae:10.203.31.9\\instance1;integratedSecurity=true;
```

Reccommend starting by looking at documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/legacy/ms378428(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

> The JDBC driver supports the use of IPv6 addresses with the connection
> properties collection, and with the serverName connection string
> property. The initial serverName value, such as
> jdbc:sqlserver://serverName, is not supported for IPv6 addresses in
> connection strings. Using a name for serverName instead of a raw IPv6
> address will work in every case in the connection. The following
> examples provide more information.
>
> To use the serverName property
>
> jdbc:sqlserver://;serverName=3ffe:8311:eeee:f70f:0:5eae:10.203.31.9\instance1;integratedSecurity=true;