# Cannot Start OpenALPR Docker Container

Tags: docker, openalpr

I've seen a post similar to mine but mine's a bit different. I feel I maybe doing something wrong.

I've created [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/blob/master/Dockerfile) in a folder. Then in that folder:

```
docker build -t openalpr https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr.git
```

All went well: `docker images`.

**Create a container:**

```
docker create --name foocontainer <IMAGE>
```

Now, `docker container ls -a` I see my container. I need to ssh into it so I need to start before attach? `docker start <container id>` No message after that so I then `docker ps` I see nothing. I need to `docker attach <container id>` so I can run `bash` commands. Any help? Im on a Mac.

Comment: Use `docker container exec -it foocontainer /bin/bash`

Comment: This might also help you: [How to get into a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172605/how-to-get-into-a-docker-container)

Comment: @tgogos Thanks but it's not runnning: `Container 1f1fe68c6690062c0e4f0ec92281986c12f4da17211c8f6b41595e43fed3b47e is not running`

Comment: try docker ps -a . what is the status of your container?

Comment: When the main process of a container stops, the container exits. Try to think of a container as a process, not as a VM. Probably your container starts and stops immediately.

Comment: @IuriiDrozdov `1f1fe68c6690        openalpr            "alpr"              2 days ago          Exited (1) 32 minutes ago                       cranky_bassi`

Comment: Can you start it again, to tell us what happens?

Comment: Ok, this is new. I got `libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394` after running `docker start -a 1f1fe68c6690`

Comment: docker logs container (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) might help as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done the following which might help you debug and understand Docker better.

1. Use `CMD` instead of `ENTRYPOINT`. The basic reason is to be able to override `CMD` when you run a new container. Read more about this practice here: [What is the difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT in a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile). So, I have changed your `Dockerfile` a bit...

   ```
   entrypoint ["/bin/sh","-c"]
   cmd ["alpr"]
   ```
2. Build your image again

   ```
   docker build -t openalpr .
   ```
3. Run a new container like this:

   ```
   docker container run -itd --rm --name=foocontainer openalpr bash
   ```

   Explained: `--rm` container will be removed after exit, `bash` overrides the `CMD` provided in your Dockerfile. **A container is up as long as this `CMD` runs**. At your case, `alpr` failed and the container exited. Now it will stay up.
4. If a container is up, you can "get inside" to type commands like this:

   ```
   docker container exec -it foocontainer bash
   ```

From this point now, you will be able to run `alpr` and see why it fails without the container being stopped.

I hope I've shed some light... :-)

Comment: Thanks. I shall update you before end of day (UK time)