# How to access a docker container through SSH?

Tags: docker, ssh

I am currently **thinking** of building a docker image for my ipython parallel nodes. Because its a pain to configure each manually with commands. Will i be able to access this image (located on a different PC on my LAN) simply by typing ssh user@ip on my laptop (Master Node)? How do i get the ip of the docker image running on my Node?

Comment: This is partly a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172605/how-to-get-into-a-docker-container), but you're actually asking at least two, possibly three different things here.

Comment: Replace the word "docker container" with "isolated application" to understand why this question is going against the grain. It's possible to do things like run an sshd server in a container namespace, but if your app isn't an sshd server, this is probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

> Will i be able to access this image (located on a different PC on my LAN) simply by typing ssh user@ip on my laptop (Master Node)?

You cannot ssh into a container unless you arrange to run `sshd` inside that container.  Normally that's not necessary; as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30173220/147356) explains you can simply use `docker exec` to access a running container.

> How do i get the ip of the docker image running on my Node?

First, a note about nomenclature: an *image* is just a collection of files.  A *container* is what you get when you start services from an *image*.  In other words, it doesn't make sense to ask questions about accessing or getting the ip address of an image.

You can get the ip address of a container using the `docker container inspect` command, which will show you a variety of information about your container.  However, this may not be what you want: the ip address of the container will be a private ip address on a docker internal network that is only accessible from the host where you're running docker.

You provide remote access to services by using port forwarding (the `-p` flag to `docker run`).  For example, if you're running a webserver on port 8080 inside a container, you could make that available on port 80 on your host doing something like:

```
docker run -p 80:8080 mywebserver
```

[This document](https://runnable.com/docker/binding-docker-ports) describes in more detail some of the options related to port forwarding.