# How to ssh into the services create using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This is my docker compose file

```
version: '2'

# based off compose-sample-2, only we build nginx.conf into image
# uses sample site from https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/agency/

services:
  proxy:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '80:80'
  web:
    image: httpd
    volumes:
      - ./html:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

Now can I ssh into any of the services which gets creats when I run docker-compose up

Comment: Maybe this will help you: [How to get into a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172605/how-to-get-into-a-docker-container)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get into a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172605/how-to-get-into-a-docker-container)

Answer (score 32):

The standard mechanism is not to `ssh` into containers, but to connect to a container using `docker exec`. Given a container Id like `3cdb7385c127` you can connect (aka `ssh` into it) with

```
docker exec -it 3cdb7385c127 sh
```

or for a full login shell if you have bash available in container

```
docker exec -it 3cdb7385c127 bash -l
```

You can still `ssh` into a container if you want to, but you would need to have a `ssh` server installed, configured and running and you would need to have access to the container IP from outside or redirect container's :22 onto some port on the host.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way is to run the `docker-compose exec` command:

```
docker-compose exec web /bin/bash
```

with the latest version of docker, since "Docker Compose is now in the Docker CLI", you can do:

```
docker compose exec web /bin/bash
```

If you do want to use the pure docker command, you can do:

```
web=`docker container ls |grep web |awk '{print \$1}'`
docker container exec -it $web /bin/bash
```

or in a single line:

```
docker container exec -it `docker container ls |grep web |awk '{print \$1}'` /bin/bash
```

in which we find the container id first, then run the familiar `docker container exec -it` command.

As it is mentioned in the question, the service containers have been created by running `docker-compose up`. Therefore I don't think `docker-compose run` is appropriate answer, since it will start a container in my test.

Answer (score 3):

1. do '`docker ps`' to get the names and docker id for your container.
2. do '`docker exec -it <docker_id> /bin/bash`'

this will give you bash prompt inside container.

Comment: Note: for me the command was `docker exec -it <docker_it> /bin/bash`

Answer (score 2):

If you specify `container_name` in your docker-compose.yaml file, you can use that to log in with the `docker exec` command.

Example:

```
django:
    container_name: django
    more_stuff: ...
```

Then, to log in to a running docker-compose:

```
docker exec -it django /bin/bash
```

This works better for me as I don't need to check the current running ID and it's easy for me to remember.

Answer (score 2):

While using the `docker` command also works, the easiest way to do this which does not require finding out the ID of the container is using the `docker-compose run` subcommand, for example:

```
service="web"
docker-compose run $service /bin/bash
```