# How to access docker app in the host machine?

Tags: docker

I am trying to dockerize my angular app. Below is my docker file, but I could not access the app in the port 4200. I don't know what is wrong in my configuration. It is angular-cli app. Can you please help me find it?

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80 4200

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

docker container run --publish 4200:4200 ngdockerapp

```
0ab397bc6233        ngdockerapp         "npm run start"     37 seconds ago      Up 35 seconds       80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4200->4200/tcp   ngdockerapp_ng_1
```

But I couldn't access the app in the host with 4200 port. I could see it is starting inside the container fine.

**Project Link:**

https://github.com/manojp1988/ngDockerApp.git

Comment: can you add here the output of 'docker ps' command please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you're using ng serve in the container without specifying the host.
ng serve will by default only serve for 127.0.0.1. you can change that by using the --host parameter.

documentation about serve: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/serve

I added a pullrequest to your repo to fix it: https://github.com/manojp1988/ngDockerApp/pull/1

Answer (score 0):

If you run `docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash`, you can access the container. check this out [How do I get into a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172605/how-do-i-get-into-a-docker-container)

Comment: Yes, I did. I could see the angular logs saying that it is listening on 4200 port localhost.

Comment: @Manoj, could you please accept this as an answer if it answered your question?

Comment: Sorry, actually it did not.