# how to enter running docker container and check machine learning training result?

Tags: docker, machine-learning, deep-learning

I run machine learning model in docker container. The model will go through train , eval , test and interactive 4 process. I use following ways to start docker:

```
sudo docker run  --runtime=nvidia --name tensorflow_bert_dst -it  -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:1.13.2-gpu-py3-jupyter
```

The process of training is so long that I close the terminal and let docker running in the server. Several hours later, I want to use following method check the result and interactive with the model.

```
docker attach tensorflow_bert_dst
```

But the docker hang and do not show any result, how to enter the running container and see the last time result and interactive with my model?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get into a Docker container's shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172605/how-do-i-get-into-a-docker-containers-shell)

Comment: I tried and it not I want. Because it can enter docker container but I can't see the result

Comment: Could you give reference on how you runmachine in docker, I 'm interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the logs of docker containers via:

```
docker logs -f <containerid/name>
```

Please note this command shows the logs of the main process of the container (the process that you started the container with and this process should log to stdout/stderr.

So if you start your container like:

```
docker run --name mylongrunningcontainer <image name> <long running command that outputs to stdout/stderr>
```

then you can check the output anytime with:

```
docker logs -f mylongrunningcontainer
```