# Docker-compose runs with successful build but one container missing

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a basic **docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '2'
services:
  hvac_backend:
    build: ./HVAC_backend
    ports:
      - 8000:5000
  hvac_frontend:
    build: ./HVAC_frontend
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

and the two following **Dockerfile**s being *HVAC_frontend*:

```
FROM nginx:1.17.8

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

and *HVAC_backend*:

```
FROM balenalib/beaglebone-black-alpine-python:3-3.11

MAINTAINER Muller

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]

CMD ["app.py"]
```

When I run a normal `docker build` and `docker run` on the the *HVAC_frontend* nginx runs fine on localhost:80. When I do a `docker-compose up -d` I get a output of:

```
Creating hvac_balenaos_hvac_backend_1  ... done
Creating hvac_balenaos_hvac_frontend_1 ... done
```

but after a `docker ps` only the HVAC_backend is running

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
249be0be515a        hvac_balenaos_hvac_backend   "python app.py"     10 seconds ago      Up 9 seconds        0.0.0.0:8000->5000/tcp   hvac_balenaos_hvac_backend_1
```

Any clues? Feels like I'm just missing something small. What happened to *HVAC_frontend*?

Comment: One of your containers failed to come up - check the logs, eg `docker logs hvac_balenaos_hvac_frontend_1`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your backend container starts properly but stops because of some exception.

run this command:

```
docker ps -a
```

to list all containers even this which are stopped.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I have a ```hvac_frontend_1  | standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"```

Comment: Here you have also helpful instruction on how to go inside the container from the command line:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30173220/2275775