# Cannot connect to MySQL db using docker container

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I wrote an application in `Typescript` which use `Typeorm` to interact with a `MySQL` database. When I run the app using `npm run dev` which is a `package.json` script, the connection is working fine with these credentials:

```
"type": "mysql",
"host": "127.0.0.1",
"port": 3306,
"username": "root",
"password": "root",
"database": "mydb",
```

but when I launch my `Docker` container I get:

```
> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
> errno: -111,
> code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
> syscall: 'connect',
> address: '127.0.0.1',
> port: 3306,
> fatal: true
```

I cannot figure out of this problem, I also tried to change `127.0.0.1` with `localhost` but same problem. That's weird 'cause I'm using `Dbeaver` to connect with my `LAMP` which is a `Docker` container container too and I can establish the connection.

Seems a problem related only with the containers connection, maybe the container of the app doesn't know the network `127.0.0.1`?

This is my image file:

```
FROM node:stretch-slim

WORKDIR /myapp

COPY package.json ./
COPY ./dist ./dist

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 4000
ENV NODE_ENV development
ENV PORT 4000
ENV URL http://localhost:4000
ENV JWT_SECRET secret

CMD ["npm", "run", "start", "dev"]
```

and this is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: myapp
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '4000:4000'
```

for compile my containers I did: `docker-compose up --build`

What is wrong? As you can see from my `lamp` container each port is correctly exposed:

[image]

Comment: `lamp_db_1` is the DB hostname, use that instead of localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: @abestrad if I do so I get: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND lamp_db_1

Comment: Assuming they're in the same `docker-compose.yml` file (those container names suggest they are) the Compose service block name `db` will also work as a host name.  `localhost` in Docker is almost always "this container" and not another container or the host.

Comment: @DavidMaze mysql is running on another container

Comment: @abestrad its working if I specify as `host: 172.17.0.1`, but it is possible share the network of mysql container?

Comment: How are you declaring your networks in compose? By default it sets up a single network for your apps. Each service should join the default network and will be reachable by others on that network. and **discoverable** using the hostname (container name)

Comment: @abestrad I didn't, could you suggest some useful resource for doing so? Or maybe could you write an answer to use mysql network from other container? Thanks

Comment: [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) is useful background material; it describes what setup Compose does for you automatically, and what host names will be reachable by default.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that each container use their own network, even though I exposed the `mysql` container on port `3306` I cannot access to `mysql` from the `myapp` container, because `myapp` container use another network.

So executing the following command: `docker network ls` I was able to list all the networks available, and then I did:

```
docker network inspect bridge
```

which has returned the following `gateway`: 172.17.0.1

The solution would be to replace `localhost` with `172.17.0.1`. But I don't like the following solution too much, so I rebuilded the `myapp` image adding previously `network_mode` inside the `docker-compose.yml`, so now I have:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: myapp
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '4000:4000'
    network_mode: 'host'
```

as documentation says:

> If you use the host network mode for a container, that container’s network stack is not isolated from the Docker host (the container shares the host’s networking namespace), and the container does not get its own IP-address allocated. For instance, if you run a container which binds to port 80 and you use host networking, the container’s application is available on port 80 on the host’s IP address.

I don't know if there is a better solution out there, I'm a `Docker` noob so far, so maybe someone more expert on this could propose a better solution to share a container network such as `mysql`, and then access to that shared network from others containers.

Another solution would be `"host": "host.docker.internal"`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `localhost`, let's replace it with `host.docker.internal`. This will allow you to connect with your local db

Comment: Saved my day too!   Thank you!   This needs tagged as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

### `docker-compose`

`docker-compose` isn't limited to just one service, you can have the whole system, which, in your case, means the DB server, your app, and all the other things.

You can change your `docker-compose.yml` file to something like below (MySQL bit copied from https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql )

```
version: '3'
services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  app:
    container_name: myapp
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '4000:4000'
```

### Networking

Because your containers are brought up in the same `docker-compose`, by default they have access to each other by hostname e.g. `app`, and `db`. To try this out, bring them up, `docker attach/exec` to `app`, and try a `ping db`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30173220/1148483

This means that in your app, you can use `db` as the DB host config.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, anyway, if I use `db` as host I get `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`

Comment: With both of them running in the same `docker-compose` file?

Comment: nope, `lamp` and `myapp` have two different `docker-compose` files, they are two different containers

Comment: Yes, what I'm saying is that you are not restricted to one container or base image in one dockerfile, and having multiple is actually its purpose.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not able to access to lamp network (mysql) from myapp container

Comment: Have you put MySQL and your nodejs app in the same compose file?

Comment: the compose file is different check them out: https://pastebin.com/wkSrk0Md

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217255/discussion-between-a-moustache-and-sfarzoso).

Comment: sfarzoso and @Andrei Mustață  .. did it get resolved ?  I am facing a similar issue and not sure how to fix it... Any leads would be helpful.  Thanks !