# how to view docker files after creation?

Tags: docker

I have create a docker and it seems that some files and folders weren't copied to the docker
or copied to other folder in docker from what I think.

- Is it possible to view the docker files and folder after creation ?
- Can I view the files and folder of the created docker using `cd / ls commands` ?

I'm using `linux os`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get into a Docker container's shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172605/how-do-i-get-into-a-docker-containers-shell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can log into a **running** container like this:

- Verify that container is running: `docker ps`
- Log into container: `docker exec -it $(docker ps -aqf "name=<name of your container>) /bin/sh`
- If your container does not start up correctly because of the missing files, you can overwrite its command to debug it: `docker run -it <your image> /bin/sh`

Note: If your container has bash, you can also use `/bin/bash` at the end of comments above.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the folder of the container attaching with **docker attach**
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/

Personally i use Portainer to see and access my containers
https://www.portainer.io/installation/