# How do you add a file directory to a Docker image?

Tags: docker

I have downloaded a repository from Docker Hub by running the Docker Pull command. This was successful but I now need to add a new file directory so that I can copy a file from my local machine. I think I have managed to copy the file to the image but I do not know how to put it in the new directory.

Could someone help with some instructions on how to copy a file from my local machine to a new file directory on the image?

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a new image and needs to copy files to the image you must use `COPY` a file and `VOLUME` to map a volume, [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume) will help you most

If you are just running an image and needs to map a local directory to the container you should use `volumes (--v)` to achive that, read [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am still a little confused as to how to go about this. The instructions I have been given is that two configuration files must be placed in a folder that is mounted in the Docker container, and the configuration files should be put in ./example/. I cannot run the image without the configuration files.

Comment: When you execute the run command, you could include: `docker run ... --volume=DIR_IN_YOUR_PC:DIR_IN_CONTAINER`, that will map the directory from your PC (aka host) to containers one you configurate

Answer (score 1):

There is the command that you should use [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/)

Example of usage:

`docker cp local-file.jar <CONTAINER>:/home/app.jar`

A similar question with many answers [How to copy files from host to Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/how-to-copy-files-from-host-to-docker-container/31971697#31971697)

Comment: Thanks. I have run the command but I get the following error:

`PS C:\Users\Darren\OneDrive\Desktop> docker cp micro.conf 836539dcf6e1:/example/micro.conf
Error: No such container:path: 836539dcf6e1:\example
PS C:\Users\Darren\OneDrive\Desktop>`

Comment: Do I get the error because the directory does not exist?

Comment: @Darren that is possible. Please create the directory firstly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to figure out how to create a directory at the moment!

Comment: @Darren, just to connect to the container than mkdir /example.

Comment: @Darren here another question with answers on how to get into container: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172605/how-do-i-get-into-a-docker-containers-shell