# How to get back to shell in nodejs:latest docker image?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-image

I'm newbie to docker, I tried this command

```
docker run -it node:latest
```

then, I was in the node REPL,

```
Welcome to Node.js v16.3.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
>
```

I tried control+c ,but this quit the image,

Is there any way to go to the shell in this image?

Comment: That container is just running a `node` processes; it doesn't have your application source code or anything else in it.  You wouldn't typically "go to the shell" any more than if you were running a `node` REPL in a non-Docker development environment.  You might look at Docker's [Sample application](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) tutorial, which walks through a typical workflow of building and running a custom image, even based on Node.

Answer (score 18):

In order to overwrite the entry point of the docker image you're using, you will need to [use the `--entrypoint` flag in the run command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#entrypoint-default-command-to-execute-at-runtime).

`docker run -it --entrypoint bash node:latest`

For better understanding on how to work with already running docker container you can refer to the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172605/how-do-i-get-into-a-docker-containers-shell?rq=1)

Comment: When I was in the REPL , is there a way to get back to shell?

Comment: this worked for me - note that `node:latest` is the name of the container - so for me my full command was `docker run -it --entrypoint bash foo`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is once you have your container running and you are in a node process.

So you start of like this

```
docker run -it node:latest
```

Then you can open up another terminal and then bash into it

```
docker exec -it <container id> bash
```