# Accessing the shell of a docker container and running multiple commands, always keeping the current shell state

Tags: docker, docker-api

I am currently creating a wrapper kernel for Juptyer Notebook that can interpret Dockerfiles.
Do do this I am building a new image after each executed cell and storing the resulting image id.
I am using the [Low Level API](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#) docker provides.

By now I was able to execute single commands by doing the following:

The image only consists of the following:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
```

```
#sleep infinity to keep the container from exiting
container = api.create_container(image_id, command="sleep infinity") 
api.start(container=container)

def execute_command(command):
    exec_info = api.exec_create(container=container, cmd=command)
    response = api.exec_start(exec_id=exec_info.get('Id')).decode()
    print(response)
```

If I now call something like `execute_command("ls")` it works and prints out the directories.
If I now want to change the current directory I need to call `execute_command("/bin/bash -c cd dev")`. If I now repeat the `ls` command I get the same output as before.
How can I manage to send multiple commands (one after another, not knowing all commands beforehand) and always keeping the current state of the shell?
Basically "saving" the shell as a variable and sending my commands to it.

I've read something about attaching to the docker container via `api.attach()` but I'm not sure if this leads to my goal.

I hope I made myself clear on what I want to achieve!

Comment: Have you considered how you might do this without Docker?  (`subprocess.call('cd ...')` will similarly be a no-op, for example.)  It sounds like you're trying to reimplement `docker build`, would just running that make more sense?

Comment: You made a good point there.
It might not be exactly what you meant but you got me the right idea: I just spin up a terminal session in jupyter lab and execute the commands to interactively [interact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172605/how-do-i-get-into-a-docker-containers-shell) with the container's shell.
This also removes the need to implement the terminal myself in the wrapper kernel